# Where should I put an executable jar?

Tags: java, filesystem

Executable files (built programs and shell scripts) normally go in /bin or /usr/bin but what about a jar file? It is a 'program' making me think it should go in bin,  but on the other hand it requires a script to start it.

I have a very simply script to start the jar.

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

But where should I put the jar file its self?

Comment: `/usr/share/java` could be one place. Though if it's a user .jar it belongs more in one directory in your $HOME

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on you, i would suggest not to use any place designated to store system wide binary files. Although you can put it in `/usr/local/bin` or any other designated place to store system wide binary files but as it is not a regular binary file you better put somewhere else. Your home directory may be a good place too.

Actually it does not matter where you are putting this as long as you are going to use full path to call it:

```
java -jar /path/to/myapp.jar
```

Whereas if you want to put it somewhere in your `PATH`, you can add the path to the directory containing the file to the `PATH` (put it in `~/.bashrc`):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory
```

Make sure the directory does not contain anything else (otherwise it would be a great place for running random malicious commands !!).

Now you can also create an alias of the command, for example:

```
alias myapp='java -jar /path/to/myapp.jar'
```

put it in `~/.bash_aliases`. Now you can run the application by just typing:

```
myapp
```

Comment: have a look at the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure) for further information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no definite location that you '*should*' store your executable jars in. It is based solely on user preference. 
I find that keeping my executable jars on the desktop works best so i don't need to continuously travel through my file system to use them which can sometimes get lost if your memory isn't the best.

Also little sidenote, if you install Java 8 then you can use Oracles Java 8 Runtime so you can just double click on the jar.
Hope I helped answer your dilemma.